# Views and http methods in Django rest framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm starting with Django and Django Rest framework and coming from MVC world (groovy/grails, elixir/phoenix), I'm a bit confused with some things.
I think Views work like Controllers right? But I'm used to define routes pointing to a specific action in the controller (it could be a get or post), but in django seems that a View is a less flexible Controller. I don't want to use all the shortcuts like generic views or something like that, I just want to define a View class, and define different methods specifying the HTTP method they'll serve, is that possible? Most of the documentation online is oriented to CRUD applications, but I want something more than that, and with less abstractions.
Also, it seems that all the views are located in views.py, what happens if I'm working in a big project? that file is gonna be huge and difficult to maintain, is it a good practice to split that views.py in different files?

thanks

Comment: You don't have to have your views is `views.py`. Put them wherever you want. Django requires explicit imports. DRF has something called `ViewSet` which is different from a regular django view. A ViewSet cand define multiple views for list, get, post, delete, options, patch and put in a single class. To use a viewset, you also use the DRF router between DRF and the django router. There's examples of this in the docs.

Comment: Some things I like to do are creating a services.py file to hold everything where business logic might take place, and have the views file be very simple. Also you can do a lot by adding a managers.py file to create managers for each of your Models. This is a good way to remove all the query logic from your views and just have the views handling the repsonse https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/